# Java Spark remake HIVE view to INSERT

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, hive

I have the following Java code that read a JSON file from HDFS and output it as a HIVE view using Spark.

```
package org.apache.spark.examples.sql.hive;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.MapFunction;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
// $example off:spark_hive$
public class JavaSparkHiveExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // $example on:spark_hive$
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("Java Spark Hive Example")
            .master("local[*]")
            .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://localhost:9083")
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate();

    Dataset<Row> jsonTest = spark.read().json("/tmp/testJSON.json");
    jsonTest.createOrReplaceTempView("jsonTest");
    Dataset<Row> showAll = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM jsonTest");

    showAll.show();
    spark.stop();
  }
}
```

I am having a hard tome to remake the view to a INSERT statement instead in order to INSERT the JSON into table test1 (for example).

Help is very appreciated!

Comment: Why do you want to `INSERT INTO` instead of `showAll.write().saveAsTable()`?

Comment: That works perfectly, I should have found it myself. Thank you! Btw, do you know how to change so the json-file is read from my local file system instead of HDFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save to a Hive table, you can do

```
showAll.write().saveAsTable("tableName")
```

If you want to read a local file to the executor, use `file://` to prefix the file path. Note, Spark is a distributed process, so all executors need to be able to read the file at the same location, which is why HDFS is commonly used with Spark

Comment: Just what I needed. Ty.